# How to override sonataNotificationBundle's Sonata\NotificationBundle\Iterator\MessageManagerMessageIterator class?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

Sonata Notification Bundles backend command waits for number of iterations passed to command to be completed , I want the backend command to just iterate the number of times equal to messages available. It should send all messages and exit.

So I want to override Sonata\NotificationBundle\Iterator\MessageManagerMessageIterator class.

I copied it to  Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\Iterator\MessageManagerMessageIterator , Application\Sonata is a child bundle which is generated by Sonata at the time of installation. But still it is pointing to original parent bundles class and not using this class.

The iterator is used in,

Sonata\NotificationBundle\Backend\MessageManagerBackend.php class in below method.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $types = null !== $this->type ? array($this->type) : array();

    return new MessageManagerMessageIterator($this->messageManager, $types, $this->pause, $this->batchSize);
}
```

How do I override MessageManagerMessageIterator ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) feature. It is not very clean solution, but still it will work.